# how to remove default close button in dialog page in jquery mobile 1.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile

how to remove default close button in dialog page in jquery mobile 1.0.
i'm using RC2 version.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please put this in your page or stylesheet:

```
<style>
.ui-dialog  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-notext  { display:none;} 
</style>
```

Comment: this does not work with jquery.mobile-1.2.0 anymore, [however this solution works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12467701/1545993)...

Answer (score 4):

```
<style>
  .ui-dialog  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-notext  { display:none;}
</style>
```

this doesn't work. at least with jquery.mobile-1.2.0

```
.ui-dialog .ui-header a[data-icon=delete] {
  display: none;
}
```

but this way works

Comment: **+1** thank you, your answer helped me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13809474/1545993)

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using jQueryMobile 1.0.1. In this version no need to add this line in CSS file.

```
<style>
.ui-dialog  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-notext  { display:none;} 
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have the situation that you want the close button refer to an arbitrary (not the last) page, you could also change the page to your desired close page first. Afterwards open the dialog like this:

```
// change to the "close" page first
$.mobile.changePage('#your_page_id_here');
```

now you can open the dialog and the close button will open #your_page_id_here

```
// for some reason you have to wrap it in a timeout         
window.setTimeout(
   function( data){
      $.mobile.changePage('#dialog');
   },
   1
);
```

Advantages:

- solution works for single dialogs rather than removing all close buttons from all dialogs
- seamless integration on a single point of code
- history manipulation is not recommended, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262629/how-to-modify-jquery-mobile-history-back-button-behavior)