# JQM: how to detect first page reload after a "data-rel='back'" button on internal second page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm writing a jQuery-mobile application.

In my home ("first") page I link an internal ("second") page with a custom link (<a href="...">).

In my first page I need to detect user's click on a "data-rel='back'" button on the second page (and first page is going to be shown again).
I did try

```
    $(document).bind('pageinit')
```

and

```
    $(document).bind('pageshow')
```

with no success.
Note that using

```
    rel="external"
```

$(document).bind('pageinit') does fire, but that's not what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$.mobile.urlHistory` ([How to modify jQuery mobile history Back Button behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262629/how-to-modify-jquery-mobile-history-back-button-behavior)). It has `activeIndex` which is your current index in the history stack, and `previousIndex`, which of course is your previous index.

So, to detect if user is coming from your second page by clicking the 'back' button, you can either:

check the hash of the page they are coming from:

```
var previous = $.mobile.urlHistory.previousIndex;
var origin = $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[previous].hash; //you may need to do some regex here
if ( origin === "second" )
```

or generally:

```
// user clicked on 'back' button
if ( $.mobile.urlHistory.activeIndex < $.mobile.urlHistory.previousIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer, even if I will not test it because I did solve by some other mean, which - I'm sorry - I currently do not remember... :-(

Comment: Thanks, I thought you may solve it already, consider the time of the question. I still want to leave the solution that works for me here, just in case anyone comes across. I am new on SO, and want to contribute a little bit to the community that helped me a lot.