# jquery-mobile: How do I not add a page to the history stack

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an application which includes a series of forms, each on their own page.

I do not want some of these pages to be added to the history stack. So that when the user presses back, it skips them.

Jquery-mobile does this with dialogs. You can configure this to happen with ALL pages (or any other data-role) but not with just some pages.

Does anyone know how to do this? Alternatively, would it be possible to create a new data-role that extends "page". If that was possible, then I could disable history for all of those pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in this case, you can call `$.mobile.changePage()` by yourself:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "url", {
changeHash: false //do not track it in history
});
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been driving me nuts.

Comment: note: as of 1.4.0 changePage is now deprecated and you need to use this instead:  `$("body").pagecontainer("change","url",{changeHash:false});`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I was going berserk!!! Finally, I was able to do it with the following code that does just that!

The code below automatically prevents storing the changed locations for all pages in the current document.

Please note that it has been tested with jqm 1.4.2

```
<script>
    $(document).on("pagebeforetransition",function(event, ui){ 
        ui.options.changeHash = false; 
    }) ;
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This solution destroys dialogues flow. Dialogue opened from page B after being closed opens page A instead of B.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this question, pretty much the same as what you are trying to do.

[How to modify jQuery mobile history Back Button behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262629/how-to-modify-jquery-mobile-history-back-button-behavior)

Thanks,
Alex.