# Close button on dialog returns to the wrong page

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, knockout.js

Here's a very simple fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmSKj/

If you click the "presets" button in the header bar, it opens a dialog. If you click the "close" button on the dialog, instead of going back to the page it came from, it goes to the last page (excluding the dialog itself) on the page (the one with the content `This is another page`). How come? Is there a way to fix the automatically inserted back button so it behaves itself properly (like the "home" button I included in the dialog) or, failing that, is there a way to remove the close button.

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <header data-role="header">
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <a href="#presets" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="pop" data-rel="dialog">Presets</a>
    </header>
    <article data-role="content">
        <div>This is the main page</div>
    </article>
</div>
<div data-role="page">
    This is another page
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="presets">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Presets</h1>
        <a href="#index" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content">
        This is a dialog!
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

As Taifun pointed out, the problem is the lack of an id on the page. Adding an id fixes my first fiddle. However, my real situation is a little more complicated, as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmSKj/2/

Here I am actually creating pages dynamically using knockout, and I assign IDs to those pages via data binding, but, it seems, those ids are not recognized by jQuery Mobile for some reason. If you look with Firebug, you can see that the ids are correctly added to the attributes of the pages, but when you close the dialog, you end up on page 3 rather than the original page.

**Update 2**

Simple fix, I just added a dummy id to the bit of html that knockout is going to use as a template:

```
<!-- ko foreach: pages -->
<div data-role="page" data-bind="attr: {id: name}" id="dummy">
    This is <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mmSKj/4/).

The dummy id is replaced by knockout, so links to that page work correctly and jQuery mobile seems to be happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an `id` to your other page

```
<div data-role="page" id="anotherpage">
    This is another page
</div>
```

then it will work, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmSKj/1/)

Comment: Ok, so that fixes the problem for my fiddle but, of course, my real system is a little more complicated. In that those extra pages are dynamically created by knockout and they do have IDs, but it seems that jQuery Mobile is ignoring them. It's probably another problem caused by the order of when jQuery Mobile does it's thing and when knockout does it's binding.

Comment: Alright, I think I've found a solution. It's stupid and hacky, but if I just add a fake ID to my template, it seems to make jQuery mobile happy enough that it works. Knockout will replace the id via data binding to the correct id, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

coming back to another solution, because you mentioned: **is there a way to remove the close button?** Yes, just add this style, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12467701/1545993)...

```
 <style>
   .ui-dialog .ui-header a[data-icon=delete] {
     display: none;
   }
 </style>
```

and another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmSKj/3/) to demonstrate that

Comment: Thanks again. I haven't tried it, but I'm sure it probably works. The only disadvantage of this kind of approach is that it may break in future versions of jQuery mobile if they decide to change the layout or class names.